# What is the convention for ordering the controller actions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

Given a controller which implements all the CRUD actions: `new`, `create`, `delete`, `edit`, `index` `show`, `update`, and also a few custom actions, is there any conventional (official or not) order these action should adhere to?

Comment: I found it constructive

Comment: As proven by the only answer, this question can be replied in a way "supported by facts, references, or expertise". Apart from that, there could be other answers based on widely recognized style guides.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The "official" order (as generated by the rails scaffold) is the following

`index` `show` `new` `edit` `create` `update` `destroy`

Although I always do `index` `show` `new` `create` `edit` `update` `destroy` because I think it's a tad more logical to have the actual action that does the work, like `create` and `update` after the `new` and `edit` actions.

Comment: And where should I put custom actions ?

Comment: I always put them after the normal actions, that way I can quickly find what I want because it's the same in every file.

Comment: It's also a good practice to sort the custom actions alphabetically.

Comment: IMO, custom actions are unnecessary and usually it is better to use a controller for custom actions as they typically represent a sub-resource in some form.

Comment: @BenWest What do you mean "it is better to use a controller for custom actions"? Isn't that what we're talking about, or are you saying that it's good practice to have a separate controller dedicated to the custom actions? Genuinely curious on this as I'd like to clean up some of our heavier Controllers.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter If you have a custom action `publish` I recommend a 'PublicationsController` with a `create` to _publish_ and `destroy` to _unpublish_ for example.

Comment: @BenWest Thanks for the reply. I'm not fully on board with this approach yet but I'll give it some more thought as to what makes the most readable code and predictable structure. It's a constant battle! :)